# what toString.call(array) actually does?

Tags: javascript

I know that call and apply are used to set the **this** explicitly in javascript.
The use of following code is to check that it is **array** object. It will console **[object Array]**.

```
var arr = [];
console.log(toString.call(arr));
```

Can anybody make me understand what code **`toString.call(arr)`** is doing?

Answer (score 5):

`toString.call(arr)` calls `toString` (whatever that is) with `this` set to the array. What it does will depend entirely on what `toString` is.

For instance, if it's `Object.prototype.toString`, it reliably produces this string: `[object Array]`. This is handy in pre-ES2015 environments for determining whether the array is an array or something else:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === "[object Array]") {
    // Yes, it's a true array
} else {
    // No, it isn't
}
```

(In ES2015, `Array.isArray` was added: `if (Array.isArray(arr))`.)

The reason you'd do that instead of just `arr.toString()` is that arrays override `toString` rather than using the one they inherit from `Object` (the `Array.prototype.toString` calls `Array.prototype.join`, producing a string that contains the joined-together entries in the array coerced to strings).